# Residuals for zero bounded data

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, residuals

So, I'm running into an interesting problem with my residual plot. For reference, I'm trying to model a response variable "exploration" for a social network. Exploration is the number of people you interact with on your team / total number of people interacted. As a result, there is a lower bound of 0 and an upper bound of 1.

I'm receiving a residual plot that is sharply sloping downward.
[image: My residual plot]

I'm using only one predictor "team size" and I'm using a GLM  of the binomial family (with the logit link function). I've attached the GLM's graph below.

[image]

Should I be worried about this residual plot? I read [in this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116370/what-kind-of-residual-plot-does-this-variable-have)  that it probably relates to my zero bound. But, they didn't offer any solutions for correction.